# Do I have to move all units in the area I have attacked?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In game of thrones, if I attacked the opponent with army of several units, and I used all of them to make sure to win. Should I also move all the units to the conquered territory in case of victory or I can choose to leave some units in their position?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, you already moved those troops during the March Orders step.**

The [rule book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/VA65_AGoT2_Rulebook_web.pdf) indicates that all troops are moved or not moved during the March Order, **before** combat begins. If you wanted to leave some troops behind, you need to do so before you begin combat and you cannot add those units to your combat strength.

> -When a player moves one or more units into an area containing units from another house, he starts a **combat** as the attacker.  See rules for combat on page 17.
>
> -Before resolving combat, all other non-combat movement from the area assigned the March Order must be completed.

This is further supported by the rules for retreating on page 21. The retreating units are currently in the embattled area, and must retreat back to the area they marched from.

> If the attacker lost the combat, his surviving units must retreat **back** to the area from which they marched.

Comment: The only way I can see someone getting this wrong, is years of playing Risk incorrectly and applying those mistakes here. The rules for GoT are pretty clear on this matter.

Comment: In addition: the player must decide whether he wants to put a power token on a vacated field before (!) he attacks. So he might end up losing a power token for nothing...